# alternative for max attribute for cross-browser html5 and PHP

Tags: php, html, max

`<input type="number" name="amount" max="6" />`
HTML5 and PHP

I am using the above code in order.php but in html5. So maybe using some PHP will solve this problem?

This works in:
Opera & Chrome

Not working in:
Safare, IE & Firefox

In Opera & Chrome it shows me a warning when I exceed value 6 and I can't proceed.

In Safari, IE & Firefox it does not show any warnings and proceeds to checkout.

Are there any alternatives to max? It needs to work in all the above browsers.

Thank you,
F4LLCON

Comment: Use something like [jquery.validate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) until HTML5 input elements are viable.

Comment: http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/ here I can read safari supports max, but it does not work with my 'yesterday' installed safari. Is there any other alternative that is very easy like 'max'? Or my best way is using jquery.validate?

Comment: Google also gave me this: http://ericleads.com/h5validate/, which should be simple enough. I'd still recommend the jQuery plugin for any "real" work because it lets you customize the validation in ways clients will want.

Comment: I've tested h5validate but still not working in firefox, safari and ie. I really need it as simple as it can get because it's for debugging a site I have gotten from school as an assignment. Our teacher gave us the website and told us 'now go and find the problem and fix it'. I've searched and tried lots of ways but nothing works. I don't think we are allowed to change the entire script. So yeah.. I'm stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to expand on what Millimoose said and suggest something called a *polyfill* to help you with this. While HTML5 forms are wonderful, they are not completely supported by every browser yet. But people spend many hours coding scripts that bring this functionality to older browsers while using the default functionality in the browsers that support it!

The one that was mentioned for you was [jQuery Tools Validator](http://www.jquerytools.org/documentation/validator/index.html). It is really the best one for your use case as you can drop it in and not have to write tedious validation rules.

I also recommend checking out this [Placeholder script](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) for even more HTML5 goodness in your forms!

Remember when using cutting, new features to always integrate these types of scripts to allow older browsers to enjoy your site too.

Comment: jQuery tools validator actually works great, but I don't think I am allowed to use this validator for my assignment. Teacher is stubborn as you can imagine. He wrote a html5 book himself and he thinks he is amazing. It does not even explain what to do if something does not work like max attribute and he also doesn't help with questions. But now he gives us an assignment that we can go and pull our hairs out of our heads

Comment: @F4LLCON, Gonna be honest here, don't take this guy too seriously then. As a college student myself I know how cocky these guys get. Just keep doing things how you see them best and you'll end up with the better paying job.

Comment: I know exactly what you are saying.... But....... It's actually an exam that we had to make an report about what is not working. And Tuesday we have part two, where we have to fix the code so the website will work. But we are not even allowed to use the internet! Lol I think the entire class will fail.

Comment: Hm, didn't even know about that validator plugin, looks more solid than h5validate.

Comment: @F4LLCON Well, what you could do is look for `<input type=number>` elements on the page using pure Javascript, and implementing support for `max` by hand. This might be feasible if you only need a few of these done. If you're not allowed to prepare the fix before hand, you should still code it up front so you know what to do at the exam.

Comment: @millimoose It's pretty nice actually. A bit of a pain with where to place the error elements but no showstoppers.